# ¿Extraer los grupos de un fichero XML con XPath?

Tags: xpath

Tengo un XML como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<productos>
    <TITULO>DATOS TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
    <producto>
        <cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
        <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
    </producto>
    <producto>
        <cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
        <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
    </producto>
    <producto>
        <cod_prod>1012</cod_prod>
        <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
    </producto>
    <producto>
        <cod_prod>1612</cod_prod>
        <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
    </producto>
</productos>
```

Necesito agrupar los producto por zona.

Con la instrucción:

```
distinct-values( //producto/cod_zona )
```

Obtengo:

```
10
20
30
```

Necesito obtener lo siguiente:

```
Zona: 10
Zona: 20
Zona: 30
```

Estoy probando con **concat()** pero me falla la cardinalidad, o no los agrupa, por ejemplo:

```
//producto/concat( 
    "Zona: ", 
    distinct-values( cod_zona/string( ))
)
```

produce la siguiente salida:

```
Zona: 10
Zona: 10
Zona: 20
Zona: 30
```

Necesito la forma de hacerlo en XPath, no XQuer-FLWOR:

```
for $zonas in doc("productos.xml")/distinct-values( //producto/cod_zona ) 
        return concat(
            "Zona: ", 
            $zonas
        )
```

DOM, u otras... Tiene fines didácticos y sólo se admite XPath.

Comment: has probado con 
concat(texto,'_',//otroTexto)?

Answer (score 1):

@Orici, considera la siguiente expresión:

`for $n in distinct-values( //producto/cod_zona ) return concat('Zona:', $n)`

Answer (score -1):

Con el XML de tu ejemplo
esta expresión xpath:

```
 distinct-values(//producto/concat("Zona: ", cod_zona))
```

Nos devuelve lo que pides:

```
Zona: 10
Zona: 20
Zona: 30
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias por responder. Me queda un poco lejos todo esto, pero quien sabe.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta (si entiendes que te ha ayudado y es correcta). Eso ayuda a la comunidad y al aut@r de la respuesta.  Ánimo que con tranquilidad todo va encajando.